# Stripe Event: `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` vs `checkout.session.completed`. Which one to use for successful payment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, stripe-payments

I am a bit confused between the 2 events:

`checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` & `checkout.session.completed`

I'm currently using `checkout.session.completed` so I'm curious if `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` sends any events that are not handled by `checkout.session.completed`.

My current code looks like:

```
const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session
// Handle the event
switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":
        // add user email with 'paid' status to database
    case "checkout.session.async_payment_failed":
        // send error to user that payment failed
    default:
        // Unexpected event type
        console.warn(event.type, `‍♀️ Unhandled event type`)
}
```

I have 3 questions:

1. Can `checkout.session.completed` be the catch-all of all successful payments?
2. Is there anything wrong with this code? Or it is fine?
3. Do I need to use `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` in addition to `checkout.session.completed`?

#### Edit:

I'm still confused on how when `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` is called, how do I get the `id` for `fulfillOrder`? Currently, `session.customer_details.id` gives red squiggly lines.

Is there a way to test these payment methods:

> This step is only required if you plan to use any of the following payment methods: Bacs Direct Debit, Bank transfers, Boleto, Canadian pre-authorized debits, Konbini, OXXO, SEPA Direct Debit, SOFORT, or ACH Direct Debit.

```
import { createId } from "@paralleldrive/cuid2"
import { error } from "next/dist/build/output/log"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import type Stripe from "stripe"

import { createUser, updateUser } from "@/app/db/users"
import { STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET } from "@/app/lib/env/server"
import { isAdmin } from "@/app/lib/isAdmin"
import { getLogger } from "@/app/lib/logger"
import { obfuscateEmail } from "@/app/lib/obfuscateEmail"
import { stripe } from "@/app/lib/stripe/server"

import { auth } from "@/app/auth/lucia"

const createOrder = async (session: any, logger: any) => {
    const email = String(session.customer_details?.email)
    const user_id = createId()
    try {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email,
        })

        await auth.createUser({
            key: {
                providerId: "email",
                providerUserId: email.toLowerCase(),
                password: null,
            },
            attributes: {
                email: email.toLowerCase(),
                user_id,
            },
        })

        await createUser({
            id: user_id,
            stripePaymentStatus: "unpaid",
            stripeCustomerId: customer.id,
            isAdmin: isAdmin(email),
        })
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error, `[Stripe] Error in createOrder!`)
    }

    return user_id
}

const fulfillOrder = async (id: string, session: any, logger: any) => {
    await updateUser(id, {
        stripePaymentStatus: "paid",
    })
}

export const POST = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    const logger = getLogger()
    const body = await req.text()
    const sig = req.headers.get("stripe-signature")

    let event: Stripe.Event

    logger.info("[Stripe] Processing webhook")

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig as string, STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET)

        logger.info({ type: event.type }, `[Stripe] Listening to Webhook Event!`)
    } catch (err) {
        error(err as string)
        return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${(err as Error).message}`, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }

    try {
        // Handle the event
        switch (event.type) {
            case "checkout.session.completed": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session

                const id = await createOrder(session, logger)

                if (session.payment_status === "paid") {
                    await fulfillOrder(id, session, logger)

                    const email = String(session.customer_details?.email)
                    logger.info({ email: obfuscateEmail(email) }, `[Stripe]  Successfully charged`)
                }
            }
            case "checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session

                await fulfillOrder(session.customer_details.id, session, logger)

                return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
            }
            case "checkout.session.async_payment_failed": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session

                logger.error(session, `[Stripe] Payment failed`)

                return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
            }
            default: {
                // Unexpected event type
                logger.warn(event.type, `‍♀️ Unhandled event type`)
                return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error({ err }, `[Stripe] Webhook Error`)
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Webhook handler failed. View logs." },
            {
                status: 400,
            }
        )
    }
}
```

PS: The examples I see on the internet just use `checkout.session.completed` & call it a day. I searched Github as well as used Sourcegraph & couldn't find more examples on both these events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the full answer. I just am unable to test the payment methods that return the `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded` event but i think it should work:

```
import { createId } from "@paralleldrive/cuid2"
import { error } from "next/dist/build/output/log"
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"
import type Stripe from "stripe"

import { createUser, getUserByEmail, updateUser } from "@/app/db/users"
import { STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET } from "@/app/lib/env/server"
import { isAdmin } from "@/app/lib/isAdmin"
import { getLogger } from "@/app/lib/logger"
import { obfuscateEmail } from "@/app/lib/obfuscateEmail"
import { stripe } from "@/app/lib/stripe/server"

import { auth } from "@/app/auth/lucia"

const createOrder = async (session: any, logger: any) => {
    const email = String(session.customer_details?.email)
    const user_id = createId()
    try {
        const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
            email,
        })

        await auth.createUser({
            key: {
                providerId: "email",
                providerUserId: email.toLowerCase(),
                password: null,
            },
            attributes: {
                email: email.toLowerCase(),
                user_id,
            },
        })

        await createUser({
            id: user_id,
            stripePaymentStatus: "unpaid",
            stripeCustomerId: customer.id,
            isAdmin: isAdmin(email),
        })
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error, `[Stripe] Error in createOrder!`)
    }

    return user_id
}

const fulfillOrder = async (id: string, session: any, logger: any) => {
    await updateUser(id, {
        stripePaymentStatus: "paid",
    })
}

export const POST = async (req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) => {
    const logger = getLogger()
    const body = await req.text()
    const sig = req.headers.get("stripe-signature")

    let event: Stripe.Event

    logger.info("[Stripe] Processing webhook")

    try {
        event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(body, sig as string, STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET)

        logger.info({ type: event.type }, `[Stripe] Listening to Webhook Event!`)
    } catch (err) {
        error(err as string)
        return new Response(`Webhook Error: ${(err as Error).message}`, {
            status: 400,
        })
    }

    try {
        // Handle the event
        switch (event.type) {
            case "checkout.session.completed": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session

                const id = await createOrder(session, logger)

                if (session.payment_status === "paid") {
                    await fulfillOrder(id, session, logger)

                    const email = String(session.customer_details?.email)
                    logger.info({ email: obfuscateEmail(email) }, `[Stripe]  Successfully charged`)
                }
            }
            case "checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session
                const email = String(session.customer_details?.email)
                const user = await getUserByEmail(email)

                if (user[0].id) {
                    await fulfillOrder(user[0].id, session, logger)
                }

                return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
            }
            case "checkout.session.async_payment_failed": {
                const session = event.data.object as Stripe.Checkout.Session

                logger.error(session, `[Stripe] Payment failed`)

                return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
            }
            default: {
                // Unexpected event type
                logger.warn(event.type, `‍♀️ Unhandled event type`)
                return NextResponse.json({ success: false })
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error({ err }, `[Stripe] Webhook Error`)
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: "Webhook handler failed. View logs." },
            {
                status: 400,
            }
        )
    }
}
```

You don't need to respond on every switch...case block. You can use break. Just send a final empty response near the end with `NextResponse.json({})` as it doesn't matter.

See the doc in the below answer for more info on how those methods differ. TL;DR one payment method uses ACH Cards that takes 2-3 days to send payment & that's why `async_payment_succeeded` exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's all explained in [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders#delayed-notification). You would want to (1) listen to them all, (2) modify your code to the example code in the Doc and (3) Yes.

Comment: thank you for that. see my edit, i've like 2 other questions. think i'm close so don't close the question as i'd like to answer it with full code. i wanna know how to get `id` for `fulfillOrder` in `checkout.session.async_payment_succeeded`. i'll be testing the ach payment method. please check if my code is correct? i do think it is close.

Comment: well the `id` of the Customer object associated with the CheckoutSession, if that is what you are looking for, is the `session.customer` (https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-customer) , subject to what's noted in the docs that there might not be a Customer object depending on how exactly you create the Session.

Comment: @karllekko yeah i found another way to get id. i was looking for the `user_id` that i stored in my db which i got by writing another method `getUserByEmail`. see my answer above/below. i'm curious if it is possible to test ach payments that require this big code instead of just `checkout.session.completed` event. i can't seem to find test cards for such payments. it'd be great to test if my above/below code is correct or not.

Comment: You just test them by visiting the CheckoutSession page and going through the payment steps in test mode, doing that will generate the various webhooks. There isn't really a shortcut. If you need to enter any account numbers, see https://stripe.com/docs/payments/ach-debit#test-account-numbers

Comment: @karllekko i know how to test stripe payments but i can't find a place where to put ach test account numbers like `000123456789`? that's why i'm unable to test `async_payment_succeeded`. fwiw i can test `checkout.session.completed` just fine. currently when i do stripe checkout, i only see pay with card & it asks for 16 digits number. maybe its because i'm calling `stripe.checkout.create`... idk the alternatives?